# Entity Framework Code First Exception Handling with Unit of Work Pattern

Tags: .net, entity-framework, exception, ef-code-first, unit-of-work

I have a unit of work pattern that share the same datacontext.  If an error occurs during saving I catch it, and continue unto the next event to process.  However the same error occurs as if it still has the original event that error-ed still added.  Is there a way to reset the unit of work gracefully, to remove the item that caused the original error?  I even removed the item in the catch below and it still didnt work.

I also keep a list of Events to check if the ID is already taken in a property and only retrieve it once from the database, not sure if that matters.

```
EventsRepository.Add(tournament);

                try
                {
                    UnitOfWork.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Log, Go To Next Event To Process
                }
```

UnitOfWork.cs

```
 public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private readonly IDatabaseFactory _databaseFactory;
        private DataContext _dataContext;

        public UnitOfWork(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
        {
            _databaseFactory = databaseFactory;
        }

        protected DataContext DataContext
        {
            get { return _dataContext ?? (_dataContext = _databaseFactory.Get()); }
        }

        public void Commit()
        {
            DataContext.Commit();
        }

        public void SaveChanges()
        {
            DataContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Refresh(object o)
        {
            DataContext.Entry(o);
        }

        public void Commit(bool autoDetectChanges)
        {
            DataContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            DataContext.Commit();
            DataContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share details of the UnitOfWork object and how it's implemented?  The answer to your question probably lies there.

Comment: I added the unit of work class Im working with.

Answer (score 0):

If your commit failed because of added event your unit of work failed as well. If you want to process next event you should use a new instance of unit of work because if you call `SaveChanges` for each event separately and if you want to proceed after error, those events do not belong to the same unit of work.

To remove the failed event from the current context you can try manual detaching:

```
context.Entry(tournament).State = EntityState.Detached;
```